# Did muffler shop install wrong size flex pipe?

Tags: toyota, exhaust, vibration

2003 Camry 2.4L. Noticeable vibration after the repair especially at idle with ac on and in reverse with foot on brake. They said bad motor mounts became noticeable after the repair. So I installed genuine Toyota ones which reduced vibration but not entirely. Now I’m wondering if the flex pipe used is too small making the exhaust rigid creating the vibration. [image]

Comment: It does look like the exhaust diameter necks down quite a bit for the flex pipe, so if the pipe is factory size, then yes the flex pipe diameter is too small. Whether or not that will significantly reduce performance or fuel economy is a matter of debate though. The size of the flex pipe shouldn't affect vibration though. I'd recommend checking exhaust hangers and ensuring they all have flexible rubber vibration isolators, and none have been welded tight.

Comment: Hmm even though the vibration didn’t exist before the flex pipe was installed?

Comment: During the installation of the flex pipe, something could have gotten moved which caused vibration, such as one half of the pipe being shifted so it's pressing against an exhaust hanger, but I don't think the pipe itself would cause (or fail to isolate) the vibration.

Comment: I checked and didn’t see anything out of the ordinary. The vibration isn’t a metal clunking sound it’s just vibration felt inside the cabin. My first initial thought was the exhaust was too rigid that’s why suspected smaller flex pipe